# How to trim within a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to output to a text file, with the following C# code. The problem is that my outputted information has a comma at the end of it and this won't work with the program that uses the file after. I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of this comma...

```
var toFile = Path.Combine(GetTextPath(),
    string.Format(heatname + "_{0}.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")));
            string ElementsNum = RoundedValues.Count.ToString();
            DateTime dt = System.DateTime.Now;
            var year = dt.ToString("yy");
            var month = dt.ToString("MM");
            var day = dt.ToString("dd");
            var minute = dt.ToString("mm");
            using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(toFile))
            using (TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                sw.Write("NA" + "," + dt.Hour.ToString() + "," + minute + "," + day + ","
                                      + month + "," + year + "," + "ALTEST " + "," +
                                      "ALTEST " + "," + heatgrade + "    " + "," + "    " + "," + heatname + "," +
                                      DT2.Rows[0][3].ToString() + "," + heatgrade + "," + "OE2" + "," + "," +
                                      "," + "," + "," + "," + "," + " " + ElementsNum);

                foreach (var pair in RoundedValues.Zip(Elements, (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b }))
                {
                    sw.Write(pair.B.ToString() + ", " + pair.A.ToString() + ",");
                }
            }
```

Comment: join() is your friend

Comment: I think using a `StringBuilder` would help with string concatenation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a linqy way to do it. This would use the Aggregate function of linq.

```
var x = RoundedValues.Zip(Elements, (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b })    
  .Aggregate("", (old, item) => {
            return old + (old == "" ? "" : ", ") + 
               item.B.ToSTring() + ", " + item.A.ToString();
   });
sw.Write(x);
```

Version two (go go join!) uses linq to make a array of strings containing the pairs and then combine those pairs seperated by a comma using join.

```
string [] x = RoundedValues.Zip(Elements, 
     (a, b) => b.ToSTring() + ", " + a.ToString() ).ToArray();
sw.Write(String.Join(", ",x));
```

It might be that the following would work, but I'm not where I can test it ... this sure looks sexy (mostly because it is one line and everyone loves one line solutions):

```
sw.Write(String.Join(", ",
   RoundedValues.Zip(Elements, 
     (a, b) => b.ToSTring() + ", " + a.ToString() )
));
```

Which would replace

```
foreach (var pair in RoundedValues.Zip(Elements, (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b }))
{
   sw.Write(pair.B.ToString() + ", " + pair.A.ToString() + ",");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to use linq... kinda new to this. Where would I put this in my code?

Comment: @JimmyLive - I also wrote a join version for you.

Comment: The second block is so close but its putting the number values before the elements in the loop

Comment: @JimmyLive -- oops fixed that on the 2nd and 3rd.  I had a and b switched.

Comment: nvm, i just flipped a and b. thanks! oops, just saw that you did that. got it. huge help bud

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TrimEnd`, for example:

```
var theString = "abcd,";
var trimmedString = theString.TrimEnd(new[]{','});
```

In your case, if I'm not mistaken, this is where you want it to happen:

```
sw.Write(pair.B.ToString() + ", " + pair.A.ToString() + ",");
```

If so, you can do this:

```
var pairs = pair.B.ToString() + ", " + pair.A.ToString() + ",";
sw.Write(pairs.Trim().TrimEnd(new[]{','}));
```

Comment: It wont recognize TrimEnd.. Do I need a specific reference?

Comment: `TrimEnd` has been in .net since v1.1. Did you do exactly as I have suggested it? Or otherwise? Please show your updated code?

Comment: You're right, I didnt have it exactly as you did. Still have a comma on the end of the output file though...

Comment: Do a `Trim` first to make sure you don't have trailing spaces. But even without it, it should work already. See my updated answer.

Comment: Would be best if you update your question with the new code so I won't guess where the problem is :)  Anyway, you should be doing the trim outside of the loop because that's the last line that is written to the file, isn't it?

Comment: foreach (var pair in RoundedValues.Zip(Elements, (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b }))
{var pairs = pair.B.ToString() + ", " + pair.A.ToString() + ",";
sw.Write(pairs.Trim().TrimEnd(new[] { ',' }));
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28852/discussion-between-von-v-and-jimmy-live)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the StringBuilder.

```
...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var pair in RoundedValues.Zip(Elements, (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b }))
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}, {1},", pair.B, pair.A);
}
sw.Write(sb.ToString().TrimEnd(new[] { ' ', ',' });
```